# "The fog rolled in" vs. "a fog rolled in"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Could you tell me the difference between *the fog rolled* in and *a fog rolled in*? For example:

> **The** fog rolled in and we couldn't see anything on the highway.
>
> **A** fog rolled in and we couldn't see anything on the highway.

I checke the word in a [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fog), and it doesn't give examples of the word used with *a* when used in a literal sense. Strangely enough, I checked the word *mist* in the same [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mist) , which is synonymous, and it gives examples with both *a* and *the*.
Could you explain the logic behind using *the* in my examples.

Comment: Sorry, but had you read further you would have found references to "a fog" in your dictionary. Also commonly used phrases like "The trail was half lost in fog" can be correctly written as "The trail was half lost in a fog" but the "a" is not used, it is not necessary, as we know it is singular.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but what about the context I gave? Could explain the difference?

Comment: I think it would be very unusual to use the indefinite article when talking about the weather. I would say _Fog rolled in_, (or _the fog_ if I had mentioned it earlier). In a literary context, you might find expressions like _a fine rain had begun to fall_, or the one in your dictionary, _a mist of tears_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Thank you for the helpful comment, but what about the word "mist" it has a very similar meaning, still it's used with "a"? You can see that by clicking the link I provided in the question.

Comment: The simple answer is, I don't know! Maybe because mist may be more localised than fog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to "a fog," "a shower" or "a downpour" the same way you would refer to "a storm." Each is a specific instance of a weather phenomenon.

"The fog" would also be fine here. What fog? That fog, specifically, the fog on the highway in front of us.

Just plain "fog," without an article, would also work. "Fog rolled in" uses the word as a collective noun: a reference to the phenomenon itself stands in for this specific instance of fog.

To my ear, "a fog" sounds the best of all these options, but none would be grammatically incorrect.